# ERROR: Instance failed to start -- A connection with the server could not be estabilished

Tags: windows, react-native, visual-studio-2019

While running the Windows app using react-native in visual studio getting an error like this. In local machine debug mode x86 getting error.[image]

Comment: how to run the windows app using vs 2019(react-native)

Comment: I didn't start the server. Finally, I ran yarn start cmd